How to tell if one smaller petri net pattern exist in a bigger petri net (from behavioral aspect)?
I'm working with Petri nets to model some concurrent systems, and I need to determine if a smaller Petri net pattern (let's call it Nsmall) exists within a larger Petri net (Nbig), but from a behavioral aspect rather than a structural one (there are special cases: same behavior but different structures).
In other words, I want to verify if the behavior represented by Nsmall (sequence of transitions, concurrent executions, etc.) can be found within the behaviors of Nbig. The exact structure (places, transitions, arcs) doesn't need to match perfectly, but the possible sequences of events (behavior) should correspond.
What I am currently doing is generating a reachability graph for both Nsmall and Nbig, and then I have RGsmall and RGbig.
Intuitively, I think, by checking if  RGsmall is a subgraph of RGbig can tell if the behavior of Nsmall exist in Nbig.
I think someone should have already proved it. But I didn't find relevant resources or books, and I'm unsure how to prove it in a formal way. Any guidance on this topic would be greatly appreciated!
